# Ember passing model using link-to to another resource throwing uncaught #error

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model which 'owns' other models (belongTo, hasMany) and I'm attempting to create each in a multi-step form.

I am passing the parent model, `campaign`, through with each `link-to` so it can be used when creating the other records and displaying existing children. This worked when I originally had a nested `route`, but when I change it to a `resource` the `campaign` model seemingly isn't sent through.

My router:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('campaigns', function() {

    // I originally had a this.route('step2') which I sent the model to and it works

    this.resource('campaign', { path: '/:campaign_id' }, function() {
      this.route('edit');

      this.resource('ad-groups', function() {
        this.route('new'); // new route is irrelevant in this question
      });

    });
  });
});
```

So in the `campaign/edit` router, I save the model and transition to the `ad-groups/index` route with the campaign as the model:

```
App.CampaignEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    save: function(campaign) {
      campaign.save().then(function() {
        this.transitionTo('ad-groups', campaign);
      }.bind(this));
    }
  }
});
```

But this is where it renders the template, but the Ember inspector shows it's not loading a model. And the relevant parts of my models for completeness:

```
App.Campaign = DS.Model.extend({
  adGroups: DS.hasMany('ad-group', { async:true }),
  ...
});

App.AdGroup = DS.Model.extend({
  campaign: DS.belongsTo('campaign'),
  ...
});
```

If I manually return the campaign within the `model` hook of `ad-groups/index` then Ember throws an `Uncaught #error`, and renders the template but without any of the model data showing.

**Edit:** So I tried implementing the solution below by setting the `model` as `this.modelFor('campaign')` and it threw another `Uncaught #error`. Bizarrely, when I remove the relationship in my FIXTURES it no longer errors, but of course I lose that relationship. My fixtures:

```
App.Campaign.FIXTURES = [
  // If I remove the adGroups: [1] it removes the Uncaught #error but I lose the relationship
  { id: 1, name: "Campaign #1", app: 1, adGroups: [1] },
  { id: 2, name: "Campaign #2", app: 1 }
];

App.AdGroup.FIXTURES = [
  { id: 1, name: 'My first AdGroup', bid: 2, budget: 100, campaign: 1 }
];
```

I had a similar issue to this before, and I fixed it by adding `{ async: true }` to my `campaign` model as you can see above. So this looks like it's more the issue, admittedly async confuses me a little still. Could anyone shed some light on why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

After all of this, the two part solution was:

1.) Instead of passing the `model` using the `link-to`, implementing this:

```
App.MyRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.modelFor('campaign');
  },
  ...
});
```

Which in my opinion shouldn't be necessary, but it's actually really nice in that it uses a parent routes' model - [link for reference](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_modelFor).

2.) The remaining `Uncaught #error` error that Ember was throwing was extremely unhelpful. It turns out I was linking to `adgroup` instead of `ad-group` in the template:

`{{link-to 'adgroup'}}` instead of `{{link-to 'ad-group'}}`